# Why Utilities.formatDate in a google apps script not work for a date that is derived from a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script

In my google apps script I have two lines like this:

```
var date = sheet.getRange('F5').getValue();
var formateddate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Now, when the date in cell F5 is "2/24/2015" There is no problem.  However, if there date in F5 is derived by a formula in the spreadsheet, like using "=CONCATENATE", it does not like it, and gives me this error message "Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)".  How can I make this work?

Comment: It may help to know that if it is derived this way, then I do not need to formatted the date with the Utilities, so if there is a way to check to see if the value is a date or not, that would work as well.  As in IF (date is a date) {var formateddate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','MM/dd/yyyy');}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!!

```
if (date.getDataValidations() === SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.DATE_IS_VALID_DATE)
{var formateddate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','MM/dd/yyyy');}
if (date.getDataValidations() != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.DATE_IS_VALID_DATE) {var formatedate= date};
```